# Laravel Application Exhibits Significantly Higher Resource Usage And Performance Degradation When Dockerized Vs When Running in Host Environment

Tags: laravel, docker

I am experiencing a notable difference in memory usage and performance degradation between running my Laravel application locally with PHP's built-in server or running it with PHP-FPM and Nginx installed locally compared to running it in Docker containers.

I have done some tests using a fresh Laravel project only installing Laravel/telescope.

Local environment:

- PHP 8.2.12
- Nginx 1.25.3
- Laravel 10
- MySQL 8
- MacOS

Dockerized environment:

- php:8-fpm
- nginx:1.25-alpine
- Laravel 10
- MySQL 8
- Docker Desktop on MacOS and on Linux as well

```php
// routes/api.php

...
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Ok';
});
...
```

The Dockerfile

```
############################
#       Dependencies       #
############################
FROM composer:latest as deps

RUN apk update && apk add \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    freetype-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    build-base \
    libzip-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

COPY . /app

RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction

############################
#        Base image        #
############################
FROM php:8-fpm as base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    zip \
    curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip exif pcntl pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN pecl install -o -f redis && rm -rf /tmp/pear
RUN docker-php-ext-enable redis

#############################
# Development app container #
#############################
FROM base as dev

ARG user
ARG uid

RUN adduser --uid $uid $user

RUN usermod -a -G $user www-data

RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && chown -R $user:$user /home/$user
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY --from=deps --chown=$user:$user /app/vendor ./vendor

COPY --chown=$user:$user . /var/www

EXPOSE 9000

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./docker/startup.sh"]

USER $user

CMD ./docker/startup.sh

########################
#      Web server      #
########################
FROM nginx:1.25-alpine as server

COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./ /var/www
```

**Observations:**

- When the application is served using `php artisan serve` or when served with the local nginx and php-fpm, it uses **2MB** of memory and **36ms response** time. (did many tests and took the average)
- Whereas in docker, the same codebase, same request, uses **18MB** of memory and **150ms response** time. (did many tests and took the average)

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.